# how do we copy an azure storage account table to another storage account?

Tags: powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm attempting to clone my storage tables into a different storage account. What is the best way to do this with powershell?

I've  attempted [this](https://jtabuloc.wordpress.com/2019/04/02/copy-azure-storage-table-into-another-azure-storage-table/) solution; however, at this point I'm getting this exception:

```
Copy-AzureStorageTable : The term 'Copy-AzureStorageTable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check  the spelling  of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

**How do we copy a table into another storage account?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AzCopy v10 doesn't support Azure Table Storage unfortunately. To export/import data from/to Azure Table Storage, you need to use AzCopy [v7.3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) instead.

**Note** that it doesn't support direct Table to Table copy, so you need to export the source table to local disk or Blob Storage at first, then import it to another destination table.

We have written the below PowerShell script that will download all the tables under the storage account to your local & it will upload to the destination storage account which is working fine.

**Here is the PowerShell Script:**

```
Connect-azaccount
$strgName='<storageAccountName>'
$stcontext=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $strgName -StorageAccountKey <StorageAccountKey>

$tablelist=Get-AzStorageTable -Context $stcontext | Select-Object -Property Uri,Name


foreach($table in $tablelist){
   
   $Sourceuri=$table.Uri

    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"

  .\AzCopy /Source:$Sourceuri /Dest:C:\Users\Downloads\azcopy1 /SourceKey:<StorageAccountKey>
   
}

$localist=Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users\Downloads\azcopy1\  -Exclude *.json
foreach( $item in $localist){

$tbname=$item.Name.Replace('<storageaccountName>_','').Replace('.manifest','').Replace('_','').Replace('.','')

$manifest=$item.Name.Replace('C:\users\Downloads\azcopy1\','')

 cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy" `

.\AzCopy /Source:C:\users\Downloads\azcopy\ /Dest:https://<DestinationStorageAccount>.table.core.windows.net/$tbname/ /DestKey:<DestinationAccountKey> /Manifest:$manifest /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace

}
```

Here is the output for reference :

[image]

[image]

[image]